# How do I cancel a "drag" motion on an Android Seekbar?

Tags: android, seekbar

I've been reading through the docs, and I cannot figure out how to cancel a "drag" on a Seekbar once the bar has been completed.

For example, when I drag the bar to the end, I want an event to happen. However, if I keep my finger on the screen and drag my finger past the SeekBar, it keeps firing off that event even after I reset the progress of the Seekbar. How can I prevent this action from happening?

Thanks

Comment: IMO, force-canceling an event like that seems like it would lead to an unexpected UI behavior for the user. Think about it -- the user drags the thumb to the end, (you 'cancel' dragging here), but then the user realizes they want to drag it back. But dragging back now wouldn't work because you've canceled the event.

Answer (score 12):

Try this..it works fine..

```
mSeekBar.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This is not the answer, by disabling the seekbar you change it's drawables state and therefore its color

Answer (score 7):

```
seekBarObj.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int originalProgress;

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            originalProgress = seekBar.getProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int arg1, boolean fromUser) {
            if(fromUser == true){
                seekBar.setProgress(originalProgress);
            }               
        }
    });
```

Comment: This does not seems to be the best idea..

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16236736/1068800 -> This works perfectly..