# Android seekbar how to block dragging / disable it for short time

Tags: android, user-interface, seekbar

I want to block the dragging of a seekbar if a value is true. Is this even possible? I use a seekbar as a switch. If my seekbar value is 0, and I press the button action A started. If my seekbar value is 1 and I press the button action B is started. 
I want to prevent that If action A or B is running the seekbar is dragged to another position. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You should set your own onTouchListener and just return true.

```
seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: setEnabled(false) actually blur the seekbar as a whole. If we just want to disable touch, this is the perfect work around.

Comment: If you want to switch between blocking and unblocking the seekbar, just add a global boolean variable inside the onTouchListener, e.g.: ` if (globalbooleanvar) { return true} else {return false}`

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried disabling the view?

Ref:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean)

**Update:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278616/529691

Ideally **you shouldn't be doing this**, as this is going to confuse the user. My suggestion is rethink your approach.

Comment: That means that the view is gone, thats not what I want.

Comment: Wrong. It does NOT remove the view, it disables the view from being interacted with by the user. Read your documentation.

Comment: Ah, Ok. Is will test it. Thanks!

Comment: seekbar.setEnabled(true) or seekbar.setEnabled(false) dont work. It doesnt prevent that the seekbar is moved.

Comment: mhh. Ok. Thanks. I think I will simple stop the action if the seekbar is switched.

Answer (score 5):

Set one class level variable

```
private boolean blockSeekBar = false;
```

after that set `blockSeekBar` variable as per your requirement and use in app.

```
seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return blockSeekbar;
        }
    });
```

[setEnabled(true/false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEnabled(boolean)) also choice but there view is not showing good so thats why above code is perfectly working.

Comment: I don't understand. Why `setEnabled()` is not a good option? For me it works fine.

Comment: when you set setEnabled(true/false)  then view shows some blur means its directly shown not click-able

Answer (score 0):

```
int lastProgress=0;
```

1. Keep track of the last progress when the Seekbar.OnSeekbarChangeListener is fired.

   ```
   private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener mOnSeekbarChangeListener = new 

   SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
       if (fromUser) {
           if (true) {
               seekbar.setProgress(lastProgress);
           } else {
               seekbar.setProgress(progress);
           }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
       lastProgress = seekBar.getProgress();
   }

   @Override
   public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

   }
   };
   ```

Comment: Not what OP asked for.