# Setting an android seekbar so that you have to drag it?

Tags: java, android

I have a program that increments a counter each time a seekbar is dragged to the end, but the problem is that the user can cheat the counter by simply placing their thumb at the end and making the counter go up really fast. Is there a way to prevent this behavior such that the user has to drag the seekbar from beginning to end each time they want to increment the counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement *OnSeekBarChangeListener* and check if the thumb of the seekbar was moved by user. See [this answer for code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917969/how-do-i-cancel-a-drag-motion-on-an-android-seekbar/3278616#3278616)

Or maybe you can use *ProgressBar* instead of *SeekBar*.